# How to add variable date value to days in ansible playbok

Tags: ansible

I have tried in ansible to add the days to the date variable but no luck. I have searched some examples in the internet and searched the below example and it is mentioned as current date but need to pass the variable date value here.

```
- command: "date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d '+3 days'"
  register: result
```

Can you please pass your comments here.

Comment: Variable date value to add days in ansible playbook.

Comment: Can you give an example whats the expected result?

Comment: Command works based on where the command is run. The above command will run in Ubuntu. On alpine different options are available

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to initialise the date command with an arbitrary date and then add a number of days to it. The raw command will accept (amongst other formats):

```
date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d "2018-12-17 +3 days"
```

or

```
date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d "12/17/2018 +3 days"
```

so in Ansible:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    start_date: '2018-12-17'
    num_of_days: 3
  tasks:
    - name: Add num_of_days days to start_date
      command: date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d "{{ start_date }} +{{ num_of_days }} days"
      register: end_date
    - debug:
        var: end_date.stdout
```

If you want to look into the other formats, run `info date` for the detailed man page on your system where `date` is installed.

Comment: I have another doubt regarding the variables as per the above command we used the set_fact and just wanted to use the variable instead of set_fact. I have used the below script but getting the error.                                                                                                          ---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    vars:
        start_date: '2018-12-17'
        num_of_days: 14
        date_add: date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d "{{ start_date }} +{{ num_of_days }} days"

Comment: You don't tell me what error you are getting, but looking at the code as you have added it into your comment, there are problems. I have updated my answer to match what I think you were trying to achieve.

Comment: ---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        planned_start_date: '2018-12-19'
        planned_end_date: '2018-12-25'
        change_iteration: 2
        date_diff: 2
    - command: date +'%d-%m-%Y' -d "{{ planned_start_date }} +{{ change_iteration }} days"
      register: end_date
    - debug: msg="{{end_date.stdout}}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end={{ 1 + (date_diff | int - 1) }}

Comment: Above is my code. i need to use the local variable instead of set_fact because it runs only once while performing the loop. The date should be incremented whenever the loop is executed. As of now am not getting any errors only issue is the date should be incremented.